# Update Android Support Library to 23.2.0 using VectorDrawables with srcCompat on API 21+

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

It's wonderful that pre-lollipop devices now can use VectorDrawables by using Support library 23.2.0. Though I have image display issue on API 21+, but everything works fine on lower devices. I'm using Gradle Plugin 1.5, so my build.gradle contains this:

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

Then I use next code in my layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_vector_drawable" />
```

I have declared in my parent's ViewGroup this attribute:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

But still Android Studio shows this error, but project can build and run

> "Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag ImageView"

And this what I get as a result on Android 4.3:
[image]

and Android 5.1:
[image]

Is it a bug of the new support library or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to solve your image scaling issue, have you tried setting `scaleType='fitXY'` to your ImageView?

(You can safely ignore that Lint error for now also adding `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"` to your ImageView).

Answer (score 0):

> "Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag ImageView"

You have to declare the namespace in your layout (usually in the root element):

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_vector_drawable" />
```